# memcpy causing segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm currently stuck with a segmentation fault on the following function, and believe it's likely due to the destination of the function is of type int whereas source is of type double. But not completely sure, could anyone help?

```
void main(int *x)
{
    double y;
    memcpy(x, &y, sizeof(y));
}
```

Comment: `main` in C cannot have that signature. It must be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: `double` is probably bigger than `int` on your system.

Comment: Next-Time : For future posts if you have an idea of what the problem might be, document if you've tried to work around / test that the theory.  In this case, checking if passing a double in would suffice, or checking the sizeof(double) vs sizeof(int) should have given you some idea of where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`main` first parameter is `argc` which is an integer. As it is interpreted as a pointer to int the `x` points to some illegal address. When you try do write something there, something **undefined** happens. In your case segfault.

you can try something like this.

```
#define MIN(x,y)  (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

void foo(int *x)
{
    double y;

    printf("%zu\n", MIN(sizeof(y), sizeof(*x)));
    memcpy(x, &y, MIN(sizeof(y), sizeof(*x)));
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    foo(&x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only two valid signatures for `main` are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. This definition is undefined behavior. Your code is (in practicality) trying to dereference `argc`, which is causing a segmentation fault.

I would like to note also that `double` is most likely bigger than `int` on your system. Try `long long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the integer value of the double, do this instead:

```c
//try it online here https://rextester.com/NIUA85155
#include  <stdio.h>

void my_function(int *x)
{
    double y; //if left uninitialized, it will be filled with random garbage
    y = 123.456; 
    int temp_int = (int)y; //casting to int drops fractional
    *x = temp_int; //stores integer value in int pointed by x
}

int main(void)
{
    int my_int = 0;
    my_function(&my_int);
    printf("Hello, world! %i\n", my_int);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to use memcpy for some reason, I'd recommend you use it with `static_assert()` to catch obvious problems like the one that is causing you to segfault.

```c
//try online here: https://rextester.com/THV27155
//compile with C11 support to use static_assert
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_function(int *x)
{
    double y = 123.456;
    memcpy(x, &y, sizeof(*x)); //sizeof(*x) == sizeof(int)
    static_assert(sizeof(*x) == sizeof(y), "These aren't the same size! Why are we mem copying?");
}

int main(void)
{
    int my_int = 0;
    my_function(&my_int);
    printf("Hello, world! %i\n", my_int);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
In file included from source_file.c:3:0:
source_file.c: In function ‘my_function’:
source_file.c:10:5: error: static assertion failed: "These aren\'t the same size! Why are we mem copying?"
     static_assert(sizeof(*x) == sizeof(y), "These aren't the same size! Why are we mem copying?");
     ^
```